# Print variable name using smarty

Tags: variables, smarty

Using php Smarty how can i print the variable name instead of value?

Eg. i want to show on the screen this text "{firstname}" instead of the $firstname variable value.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put `firstname` in the template file where you want it to show 'firstname'.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to include the characters `{` and `}` without them being interpreted as Smarty synax? If so, check out [the `{ldelim}` and `{rdelim}` "functions"](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.ldelim.tpl) and [the `{literal} ... {/literal}` block function](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.literal.tpl).